# Simple closed curve orientation definition

Tags: curves, orientation

> The (simple closed curved) curve istraversed counterclockwise, and said to be positively oriented, if the region **it** (what is "it")? encloses is ***always to the left of an object*** as ***it*** (what is "it"?) moves along the path.

I don't understand this statement and found a counterexample.
What "object" are we talking about? I can think of a counterclockwise traversed curve where the region it enclosed is always right of an object as it moves along the path. I found this quote from a book and don't think the quote is correct. Just draw some arbitrary counterclockwise closed curve on your desk and remove every-single object to your right and we've found a counterexample because the set of objects that are to the right of the curve is empty so there's nothing to the left of the area enclosed.

[image]

Comment: The idea is to imagine something "walking" counterclockwise along the path, as if the plane was a map and the curve was a road.

Comment: Can you please help me discern what every "it" they're using is actually refrering to? I have no idea what "it" means. The curve is a partition of the map formed by an equivalence relation?

Comment: They are refering to the curve. Any simple closed curve in the plane divides the plane in two regions, interior and exterior. If you imagine something moving along the path of the curve counterclockwise, then the interior is either to the left or to the right, in the first case, the curve is said to be positively oriented.

Comment: Is there a reason the textbook isn't using the terms "west east, and south" and uses "left, right" instead? Left and right seem to be very subjective terms and not absolute directions. I prefer east, west, south, north because everyone actually can agree on what directions we're talking about.

Comment: @Cake The author uses the subjective terms left and right because they are measured relative to a point on the curve - my sense of north-west-east-south in the plane changes if you turn me upside down, but that should not change any intrinsic properties of the curve!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine that an "object" (point) moves anticlockwise along the curve. Then the curve is *positively oriented* if the interior of the curve (the region enclosed by it) lies on the left hand side of the object.

Said in plainer terms, if you were to drive anticlockwise along a curved track, then the track is positively oriented if the region inside the curve is on your left.

**Formalisation of the above**

Say the simple closed curve $C$ in the plane encloses a point $O$. Let $P = \gamma(s)$ be a variable point which moves anticlockwise around $C$. The claim is that the point $O$ is on the left side of the tangent vector $T = \gamma'(s)$. In other words, that the angle between the vector $PO = \gamma(s) - O$ is acute; in other words that their cross product is positive. WLOG $O$ can actually be taken to be the origin, so we are only interested in the quantity $\gamma'(s) \times \gamma(s) = x'(s)y(s) - y'(s)x(s)$.

Moving anticlockwise means that the angle between $\gamma(s)$ and some fixed line (say the $x$ axis) is an increasing function of $s$. Apart from when $x=0$, this angle satisfies $\tan \theta(s) = y/x$, and therefore
$$\sec^2\theta(s) \theta'(s) = \frac{y'x-x'y}{x^2}$$
which shows that $O$ is on the left of $P$ if $\theta'(s) > 0$, in other words when $\gamma$ is positively oriented.

Comment: Ok, so if I am nascar racer driving counterclockwise around some curve, whenever I stretch out my left hand and make the left hand orthogonal to my velocitywhile driving along a curved track, my left hand will always point to the interior of the curve?

Comment: That is exactly right. I should be able to find an animation to make this absolutely unambiguous...

Comment: Although, I think they've been superfluous here - I'm pretty sure that "moving counterclockwise" on a simple closed curve is always the same as "having the interior of the curve on your left hand side".

Comment: How does one formalise this idea?

Comment: @Anakhand Too long for a comment - I've amended the answer. Let me know if anything is unclear!

Comment: When finding area ( sum= zero ) of a Figure of Eight using Green`s thm using *line integral* one loop is positive and another negative ..the way most people write the numeral 8.

Comment: @Narasimham That's true - a figure eight is not simple, though.

Comment: What do you find tough in it?

Comment: @Narasimham lol. I mean it is not a simple curve. It has self-intersections.

Comment: ok, for area to vanish the curve has to be self intersecting.